# How to find the point where Exclusion starts?

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-value

I have two versions of a `Plot`

```
Plot1 = ContourPlot[((1 - Tanh[X])/(1 + Tanh[X]))^-k == 
    JacobiP[2, k, -k, Tanh[X]]/JacobiP[2, -k, k, Tanh[X]], {X, 0.001, 
    5}, {k, -Sqrt[16/3], Sqrt[16/3]}, MaxRecursion -> 1, 
   PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, Full}, 
   FrameLabel -> Automatic, ContourStyle -> {Red}, 
   Exclusions -> 
    Flatten[{k == -2, k == 0, k == 2, 
      JacobiP[2, -k, k, Tanh[X]] == 0}]];
Plot2 = ContourPlot[((1 - Tanh[X])/(1 + Tanh[X]))^-k == 
    JacobiP[2, k, -k, Tanh[X]]/JacobiP[2, -k, k, Tanh[X]], {X, 0.001, 
    5}, {k, -Sqrt[16/3], Sqrt[16/3]}, MaxRecursion -> 1, 
   PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, Full}, 
   FrameLabel -> Automatic, ContourStyle -> {Blue}, 
   Exclusions -> 
    Flatten[{k == -2, k == -1, k == 0, k == 2, 
      JacobiP[2, -k, k, Tanh[X]] == 0}]];
Show[Plot1, Plot2]
```

I get this

[image]

You can see that for the blue plot, by excluding $k=-1$, the graphic stops at $X\approx 3.5$. I want to find numerically the point $(X,-1)$ where `Exclusion` is applied. I've tried

```
FindRoot[Limit[((1 - Tanh[X])/(1 + Tanh[X]))^-k, k -> -1] == 
  Limit[JacobiP[2, k, -k, Tanh[X]]/JacobiP[2, -k, k, Tanh[X]], 
   k -> -1], {X, 3.2}]
```

and got $X\rightarrow 18.5458$. This is further than the point I was expecting: $(3.5,-1)$.

**Edit**
On the other hand, when I tried to apply the solution given for the first case to a plot that generates two branches:

```
Plot3 = ContourPlot[{((1 - Tanh[X])/(1 + Tanh[X]))^-k == 
     JacobiP[3, k, -k, Tanh[X]]/JacobiP[3, -k, k, Tanh[X]]}, {X, 
    0.001, 5}, {k, -Sqrt[(34/3)], Sqrt[34/3]}, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
   PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, Full}, 
   FrameLabel -> {Automatic}, ContourStyle -> {Red}, 
   Exclusions -> 
    Flatten[{Table[k == i, {i, -3, 3, 1}], 
      JacobiP[3, -k, k, Tanh[X]] == 0}]];

MPlot3 = Max[Plot3[[1, 1, 1]]]
Plot4 = Show[Plot3, 
  Epilog -> {Green, PointSize@Large, Point[{MPlot3, -1}]}]
```

I got

[image]

where `Max` allows to have only one extreme. I also would like to have the other value, near $k=-3$

Comment: I think the exclusion is either falling prey to numerical errors or suffers from having a certain "thickness". If you zoom in on the plot (plot `{k, -1.01, -0.99}`), you see that it doesn't actually touch $k = -1$ for any value in the visible $X$ range.

Comment: I agree with @thorimur. Looking at `FullSimplify[((1-Tanh[X])/(1+Tanh[X]))^-k == (1/2 (1+k)(2+k)+3/2 (2+k)(-1+Tanh[X]) + 3/2 (-1+Tanh[X])^2)/(1/2 (1-k)(2-k)+3/2 (2-k)(-1+Tanh[X]) + 3/2 (-1+Tanh[X])^2) /. k -> -1]` gives `Cosh[X] == Sinh[X]`, which is never true: `Solve[Cosh[X] == Sinh[X], X]` gives `{}`. So there is no way your contour is actually touching $k=-1$ except for $X\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the points used from Plot2 by:

```
ListPlot[Plot2[[1, 1, 1]]]
```

[image]

Therefore, we need to extract all the x values and determine the maximum:

```
Plot2[[1, 1, 1, All, 1]] // Max

(* 3.53187 *)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Please, notice the EDIT in my original post.

Comment: Note that all x values for the left branch are <1.3. Therefore select first all x values <1.3 and then determine their Max.

Comment: how do I select these values in Max?

Comment: Select[Plot2[[1, 1, 1, All, 1]], #<1/3 &]

Comment: thanks. How do I get the $(X^*,k^*)$ point?, where $X^*$ is the Max I just get.

Comment: You can find this point in: Plot2[[1, 1, 1, All, 1]]

Answer (score 0):

To answer my EDIT:

```
Plot3 = ContourPlot[{((1 - Tanh[X])/(1 + Tanh[X]))^-k == 
     JacobiP[3, k, -k, Tanh[X]]/JacobiP[3, -k, k, Tanh[X]]}, {X, 
    0.001, 5}, {k, -Sqrt[(34/3)], Sqrt[34/3]}, MaxRecursion -> 2, 
   PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, Full}, 
   FrameLabel -> Automatic, ContourStyle -> {Red}, 
   Exclusions -> 
    Flatten[{Table[k == i, {i, -3, 3, 1}], 
      JacobiP[3, -k, k, Tanh[X]] == 0}]];
```

I did

```
MPlot3a = First@MaximalBy[Plot3[[1, 1, 1]], First][[1]];
MPlot3b = First@MinimalBy[Plot3[[1, 1, 1]], Last][[1]];
Plot4 = Show[Plot3, 
  Epilog -> {{Green, PointSize@Large, Point[{MPlot3a, -1}]}, {Green, 
     PointSize@Large, Point[{MPlot3b, -3}]}}]
```

Then I got

[image]

which is what I wanted